# why i fail to have string from enum?

Tags: android

I define a enum on my code:

```
public enum TimeType
{
     One("1"),
     Two("2"),
     Three("3");

     private String _friendlyName;

     TimeType(String friendlyName) {
         this._friendlyName = friendlyName;
     }


     @Override
     public String toString() {
         return _friendlyName;
     }
 }
```

Now, On some place i trying to convert the enum to a string:

```
  TimeType t1 = TimeType.One;
```

I try to do it using in more then one way .. but i getting an exception

```
 String str1 = t1.toString();                           // fail
 String str2 = TimeType.values()[t2].toString();        // fail
 String str3 = t1.name();                               // fail
```

Comment: 'Fail' is not a problem description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you forgot add `;` when you declare the enum

```
public enum TimeType{
     One("1"),
     Two("2"),
     Three("3"); // add ;

     private String _friendlyName;

     TimeType(String friendlyName) {
         this._friendlyName = friendlyName;
     }

     @Override
     public String toString() {
         return _friendlyName;
     }
 }
```

Here is the test in Java `goo.gl/evcKMq`
Here is the test in Android

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toast.makeText(this,TimeType.Two.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        TimeType t1 = TimeType.One;
        String str1 = t1.toString();

        Log.e("TAG","str1 === "+str1);
    }

    public enum TimeType
    {
        One("1"),
        Two("2"),
        Three("3"); // add ;

        private String _friendlyName;
        TimeType(String friendlyName) {
            this._friendlyName = friendlyName;
        }
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return _friendlyName;
        }
    }
}
```

The `Toast` display 2 and the `Logcat` print

> 07-12 00:05:42.892 2975-2975/com.example.newuser.testenum E/TAG: str1
>   === 1

Comment: no, sorry ... this was on my code and did not solve the problem.

Comment: @Yanshof please update your code, i have tested it and it work

Comment: Please check the demo in goo.gl/evcKMq

Comment: i see that this work on the demo - but on my android this is not working

Answer (score 1):

My Example :

```
public static enum VideoBitrate {
        HD1080("HD 1080", 0),
        HD720("HD 720", 1),
        MV480("MV 480", 2);

        private String stringValue;
        private int intValue;

        VideoBitrate(String toString, int value) {
            stringValue = toString;
            intValue = value;
        }

        public static VideoBitrate valueOf(int value) {
            switch (value) {
                case 0:
                    return HD1080;
                case 1:
                    return HD720;
                case 2:
                    return MV480;
                default:
                    return null;
            }
        }

        public int value() {
            return intValue;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return stringValue;
        }
    }
```

Use

```
Enums.VideoBitrate.MV480.toString()
```